# unity Json string results in nullreference exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, reverse-geocoding

Trying to get a location name using reverse. I am using Unity's JSONutility to parse the JSON string I get from the google API. Information doesn't get stored in my local object, so I always get a nullreference exception.

To retrieve the information I am using the UnityWebRequest class. I wrote the information to a simple text file to check it the request is actually being sent and it is, the information gets written into the text file, however when I want to create something in game out of it, it doesn't work.

I used http://json2csharp.com/ to create my C# classes based on my JSON file.

I validated the JSON file here https://jsonlint.com/

```
//This is the c# file I created out of the JSON format gotten from google
//It is validated.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class RootObject
{
    public PlusCode plus_code;//This doesn't get created at all
    public List<Result> results;//This creates a list of size 11, however the list is always empty and I don't know why.
    public string status;//For some reason this is the only variable that gets populated

    public static RootObject CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(jsonString);
    }
}

public class PlusCode
{
    public string compound_code;
    public string global_code;
}

public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name;
    public string short_name;
    public List<string> types;
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast;
    public Southwest southwest;
}

public class Location
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Northeast2
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Southwest2
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast2 northeast;
    public Southwest2 southwest;
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Bounds bounds;
    public Location location;
    public string location_type;
    public Viewport viewport;
}

public class PlusCode2
{
    public string compound_code;
    public string global_code;
}

public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components;
    public string formatted_address;
    public Geometry geometry;
    public string place_id;
    public List<string> types;
    public PlusCode2 plus_code;
}
```

And this is where I am trying to call it from.

```
public void ShowStaticMap()
        {
            //Grab GEO Data
            StartCoroutine(FetchGeoData());
            newCase.date = DateTime.Today.ToString();
            StartCoroutine(GetLocationName());//This runs.
        }


IEnumerator GetLocationName()
        {
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(geoUrl);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                var TestRootObject = RootObject.CreateFromJSON(www.downloadHandler.text).plus_code.compound_code;// This is line 147. Results in a nullreference exception.
/*
If I am to try this line, it will work without a problem.
RootObject.CreateFromJSON(www.downloadHandler.text).status;
*/
                Debug.Log(TestRootObject);//There is nothing here.
            }
        }
```

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
est.UI.CreateCaseScreen+d__19.MoveNext () (at Assets/Esteban/Scripts/ScreenTypes/CreateCaseScreen.cs:147)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)

Answer (score 3):

OK... Felling real silly here.
For anyone that ever has a similar issue... When you are creating raw classes (As in nothing that inherits from anything in Unity...) Make sure to declare them as [Serializable]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[Serializable] //THIS! On all your classes!!!
public class RootObject
{
    public PlusCode plus_code;
    public List<Result> results;
    public string status;

    public static RootObject CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(jsonString);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PlusCode
{
    public string compound_code;
    public string global_code;
}

[Serializable]
public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name;
    public string short_name;
    public List<string> types;
}

[Serializable]
public class Northeast
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

[Serializable]
public class Southwest
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

[Serializable]
public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast;
    public Southwest southwest;
}

[Serializable]
public class Location
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

[Serializable]
public class Northeast2
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

[Serializable]
public class Southwest2
{
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
}

[Serializable]
public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast2 northeast;
    public Southwest2 southwest;
}

[Serializable]
public class Geometry
{
    public Bounds bounds;
    public Location location;
    public string location_type;
    public Viewport viewport;
}

[Serializable]
public class PlusCode2
{
    public string compound_code;
    public string global_code;
}

[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components;
    public string formatted_address;
    public Geometry geometry;
    public string place_id;
    public List<string> types;
    public PlusCode2 plus_code;
}
```

Comment: Yes at least when you try to deserialize data into them ;) glad you found it yourself already